# Удаление контекстного меню в Opera/Yandex

Tags: html, css, jquery

Когда заходишь с "ПК" браузеров Yandex, Opera на страничку с видеофоном, то над ним всплывает кнопка встроенная в сам браузер о том, что видео можно посмотреть в отдельной вкладке.

Каким образом можно вырезать эту кнопку, чтобы она не портила общую картину видеофона.
Все перепробовал но безуспешно((((

Видеофон я тестил на локальном сервере "Open Server Ultimate 5.2.2"
Эти кнопки в браузерах их я отметил красным маркером на скриншотах внизу.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var controls = {
    video: $('.myvideo'),
    playpause: $('.knopka')
  };

  var video = controls.video[0];

  controls.playpause.click(function() {
    if (video.paused) {
      video.play();
      $(this).prepend('<img src="https://svgshare.com/i/BXw.svg" />');
    } else {
      video.pause();
      $(this).prepend('<img src="https://svgshare.com/i/BXF.svg" />');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.video-fon {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-fon>video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.knopka {
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 10%;
  left: 92%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-fon">
  <video class="myvideo" muted loop autoplay>
<source src="https://rocld.com/g95ru" />
</video>
</div>
<div class="knopka">
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/BXw.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создай прозрачный блок поверх видео, что бы при наведении на блок видео она не вылазила...

Answer (score 0):

**Для Opera** можно убрать так:

```
body + div[is-visible] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

У него эта кнопка прям в dom встраивается, после body.

**Для Яндекса**:

Пропишите артибут `pip="false"` к видео. Например:

```
<video class="myvideo" pip="false" muted loop autoplay >
    <source src="https://rocld.com/g95ru" />
</video>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь)
Для Opera  "body display: none" не работает все также всплывает окно(((

Comment: Вот ссылки на скриншоты(Результат в Опера)  https://ibb.co/1dcCFww  и  https://ibb.co/YdY21yH

Comment: А для яндекс false работает отлично))

Comment: @Black_Viper я проверял на новой версии Opera. Может на старых конечно не работает. Но других вариантов вроде как нет.

Comment: У вас Опера Stable 64bit  58.0.3135.107?

Comment: @Black_Viper да, также проверял на 58.0.3135.79, тоже работает

Comment: Вы проверяли на локальном сервере Open server 5.2.2? Попробуйте использовать медиафайл для видеофона, который лежит у вас в корне сайте. А потом зайдите через браузер Opera и увидите)